# Images in a React SSR Firebase App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, server-side

I am fairly new to React and I am working on building a Universal Application. I recently followed the tutorial that Firebase had posted on YouTube. It worked as expected. Then I wrote my own code so I could start on my own application. I am running into issues when it comes to firebase and my image files. I suspect it is an issue with Webpack or Node.

Update: I don’t think this is just a problem with the Cloud Functions emulator, though it should be brought up to the current node version, but I am also not seeing the images when it’s in deployment on Firebase. I’ve read some places talking about image hooks for node require, I just don’t have any idea of where to put them. Here’s a link to one that is promising... https://www.npmjs.com/package/images-require-hook

The Error from Terminal

```
firebase serve --only hosting,functions

=== Serving from '/Users/danielrehbein/Sites/express-react'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v8.3.0 but Google Cloud Functions only 
supports v6.11.5.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000

⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
⚠  functions: Error from emulator. FirebaseError: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../images/image1.jpg'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


require('asset-require-hook')({
  extensions: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'],
});

module.exports = [{

  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: ['./src/index.js',
    './res/scss/main.scss',
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // handles the react components and all other JS and bundles it to es2015 standards
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      // Handles any errant .jsx files that made their way into the project
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      // handles scss styling and writes DRY css.
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        }),
      },
      // handles any image files
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            outputPath: 'public/images/',
            publicPath: 'public/images/',
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'public/bundle.js',
    path: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
      },
    }),
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/styles.css'),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
  ],
}];
```

Component with Image file.

```
import React from 'react';

const image1 = require('../images/image1.jpg');

const Home = () => (
  <div className="home">
    <img src={image1} alt="Image_1" />
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

index.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import express from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import path from 'path';

// import main react app below.

import App from './src/App';

const resolvedIndex = path.join(__dirname, 'index.template.html');

const index = fs.readFileSync((resolvedIndex), 'utf-8');

const context = {};

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context} >
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>);

  const finalHtml = index.replace('<!-- ::APP:: -->', html);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

export let ssrApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

src/App.js

```
// import dependancies below

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import Page components

import Header from './components/header';
import NavMenu from './components/NavMenu';
import Footer from './components/footer';

// Import Pages

import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import Oops from './components/oops';


const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <NavMenu />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="*" component={Oops} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />

  </div>
);

export default App;
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  ), document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an emulator issue. Think you have upgraded node and tried to run the app and now it won't work.

try to uninstall the Google Cloud Functions with npm. You can read about the emulator here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I am not sure that is entirely my issue in this case as when I comment out the lines requiring and placing the image in the component, I do not get the error.

Comment: I suspect I need some sort of image require hook, though I do not know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've specified a public path for the image resources in your `web pack` config, you might not be able to access it directly or make an import into React component this way `require('../images/image1.jpg');` in the component, instead `require('public/images/image1.jpg')`.

Base on Your config

```
use: [{
     loader: 'file-loader',
     options: {
       outputPath: 'public/images/',
       publicPath: 'public/images/',
     },
}],
```

### Public Path

The [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) configuration option can be quite useful in a variety of scenarios. It allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application.

If you would like to import it like this `require('../images/image1.jpg');` and in your css would be like this `background-image: url(/images/image1.jpg)` then you can refactor your image config to this

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]'
},
```